# Adding a nesting layer to all elements in array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this.

```
{
    field1:"a",
    field2:[
        {nestedField:"nf1",nestedField2:"nf2",nestedField3:"nf3"},
        {nestedField:"nf1",nestedField2:"nf2",nestedField3:"nf3"}
        {nestedField:"nf1",nestedField2:"nf2",nestedField3:"nf3"}
    ]
}
```

I want to transform it to below structure in aggregation pipeline

```
{
    field1:"a",
    field2:[
        {anotherNesting:{nestedField:"nf1",nestedField2:"nf2",nestedField3:"nf3"}},
        {anotherNesting:{nestedField:"nf1",nestedField2:"nf2",nestedField3:"nf3"}}
        {anotherNesting:{nestedField:"nf1",nestedField2:"nf2",nestedField3:"nf3"}}
    ]
}
```

Comment: see `$map` to change the members of the array

Answer (score 0):

Query

- map on field2, each member will go inside the document `{ anotherNesting : member}`

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62d9e39878a49d8782851467)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"field2": 
     {"$map": {"input": "$field2", "in": {"anotherNesting": "$$this"}}}}}])
```